# Unicode character in R plot - pdf device

Tags: r, pdf, plot, unicode, encoding

I would like to make a plot which an axis title that has a [thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space) as a thousand's separator and save that plot as a pdf from R. For example I would format a number like this:

```
string <- "100\u2009000"
string
[1] "100 000"
```

Here the R-console shows the correct representation of the thin space character "\u2009" (Although here on the web it looks like a full space) Then if I plot this and send it to a pdf like this:

```
pdf("foo.pdf")
plot(1,1, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "#FFFFFF")
text(1, 1, string)
dev.off()
```

I get a bunch of warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  conversion failure on '100 000' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
2: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  conversion failure on '100 000' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <80>
3: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  conversion failure on '100 000' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <89>
4: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  font metrics unknown for Unicode character U+2009
5: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  conversion failure on '100 000' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
6: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  conversion failure on '100 000' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <80>
7: In text.default(1, 1, string) :
  conversion failure on '100 000' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <89>
```

And in the resulting pdf the number looks like this: `100...000`

I see that I can give an encoding argument to the pdf device but I have not managed to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cairo_pdf` device instead:

```
string <- "100\u2009000"
string

cairo_pdf("foo.pdf")
plot(1,1, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "#FFFFFF")
text(1, 1, string)
dev.off()
```

This worked for me and produces the pdf.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of `cairo_pdf()`. It does also work for me. But, the file size is more than double presumably because it is using bitmap: From the R help: "Note that unlike postscript and pdf, cairo_pdf and cairo_ps sometimes record bitmaps and not vector graphics. On the other hand, they can (on suitable platforms) include a much wider range of UTF-8 glyphs, and embed the fonts used. " Also I get different font scaling with cairo_pdf() compared to pdf(). Maybe this is the only solution?

Comment: Very weird description. What does "sometimes" mean in this case? The files I get from cairo_pdf have the same size as the one I got from pdf(). It is also a vector graphic so I'm confused why this would be different in your case. Sorry, I'm afraid I can't help with that.

Comment: :) Yes, I agree "sometimes" is a bit vague. This is just a quote from the manual for `cairo_pdf()`. The simple example here produces the same file size, presumably because it is so simple. The example I am actually working on is a ggplot and then results in bitmap. Therefore I was hoping to find a solution not using cairo_pdf().

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`showtext`](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext) to render the text, which is guaranteed to generate vector graphics if you use PDF. The text is converted to shapes though, which means that you can no longer select them as text.

```
library(showtext)
showtext_auto()

string <- "100\u2009000"
string

pdf("bar.pdf")
plot(1, 1, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "#FFFFFF")
text(1, 1, string, family = "wqy-microhei")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Wow, that works very nicely for me. I will actually use this in solution for my application since I avoid the problems associated with cairo_pdf() discussed above. However, I will leave the cairo_pdf() answer as the accepted solution since it probably is the best approach for most use cases.

Comment: When I use the `showtext`-approach the font differs from the default `pdf()` or e.g. `pdf(family="sans")`-calls. Do you know how to derive the standard font when using `showtext_auto()`?

Comment: The showtext approach results in a much larger file, and moreover doesn't work for all glyphs (for example \u2265 will be rendered as an equal sign)